# Calculations with 2 queries

Tags: sql-server, math

I'm trying to do a simple % calculation with 2 queries ((COMPLETED/TOTAL) *100), but with only one resulting select, but the result is not showing correctly, either show 100 or 0.

Query #1:

```
select COUNT(CODE) from TABLE1 where ORG = '111' and STATUS in ('A','COM') AND LEFT(DESC, 4) = 'JOBS'
```

Query #2:

```
select COUNT(CODE) from TABLE1 where ORG = '111' and STATUS  IN ('R', 'A', 'COM') AND LEFT(DESC, 4) = 'JOBS'
```

I could make this:

```
select ((select COUNT(CODE) from TABLE1 where ORG = '111' and STATUS in ('A','COM') AND LEFT(DESC, 4) = 'JOBS')/(    select COUNT(CODE) from TABLE1 ORG = '111' and STATUS  IN ('R', 'A', 'COM') AND LEFT(DESC, 4) = 'JOBS') *100)
```

with no succes. As i said, it shows either 0 or 100.

Query #1 result is 202 and Query #2 result is 228, so it's not a math problem...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you give us some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.CountCode / b.CountCode 
    FROM (
      select COUNT(CODE) CountCode from TABLE1 where ORG = '111' and STATUS in  ('A','COM') AND LEFT(EVT_DESC, 4) = 'JOBS'   ) a
,     (select COUNT(CODE) CountCode  from TABLE1 where ORG = '111' and STATUS  IN ('R', 'A', 'COM') AND LEFT(DESC, 4) = 'JOBS' ) b
```

Also if you want with decimal do CAST(a.CountCode as decimal(18,3))

Answer (score 0):

There's one thing you probably don't notice. COUNT(*) returns a `BIGINT`, it's does simple division as you did in primary school. You're getting **0 whole number** and 202/228 as particle, which is not being displayed.

If you'd divide 228/208, you would get 1

In order to fix that, you have to cast your number as decimal:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL, (
            SELECT COUNT(CODE)
            FROM TABLE1
            WHERE ORG = '111'
                AND STATUS IN ('A', 'COM')
                AND LEFT([DESC], 4) = 'JOBS'
            )) / CONVERT(DECIMAL, (
            SELECT COUNT(CODE)
            FROM TABLE1 ORG = '111'
                AND STATUS IN ('R', 'A', 'COM')
                AND LEFT([DESC], 4) = 'JOBS'
            ) * 100)
```